# Why am I experiencing a crash when comparing bridged CGColorRefs under ARC?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have a class for a shadowed table view that I am using in my app.

When doing the conversion to ARC, I had to change some things.  With the new class, it is crashing at the following lines: `(id)(inverse ? darkColor : lightColor)` to `(__bridge id)(inverse ? lightColor : darkColor)`.  The console says `*** -[Not A Type retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4cee70`

Before:

```
- (CAGradientLayer *)shadowAsInverse:(BOOL)inverse
{
    CAGradientLayer *newShadow = [[[CAGradientLayer alloc] init] autorelease];
    CGRect newShadowFrame =
        CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width,
            inverse ? SHADOW_INVERSE_HEIGHT : SHADOW_HEIGHT);
    newShadow.frame = newShadowFrame;
    CGColorRef darkColor =
        [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:
            inverse ? (SHADOW_INVERSE_HEIGHT / SHADOW_HEIGHT) * 0.25 : 0.25].CGColor;
    CGColorRef lightColor =
        [self.backgroundColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0].CGColor;
    newShadow.colors =
        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            (id)(inverse ? lightColor : darkColor),
            (id)(inverse ? darkColor : lightColor),
        nil];
    return newShadow;
}
```

After:

```
- (CAGradientLayer *)shadowAsInverse:(BOOL)inverse
{
    CAGradientLayer *newShadow = [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];
    CGRect newShadowFrame =
        CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width,
            inverse ? SHADOW_INVERSE_HEIGHT : SHADOW_HEIGHT);
    newShadow.frame = newShadowFrame;
    CGColorRef darkColor =
        [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:
            inverse ? (SHADOW_INVERSE_HEIGHT / SHADOW_HEIGHT) * 0.25 : 0.25].CGColor;
    CGColorRef lightColor =
        [self.backgroundColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0].CGColor;
    newShadow.colors =
        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            (__bridge id)(inverse ? lightColor : darkColor),
            (__bridge id)(inverse ? darkColor : lightColor),
        nil];
    return newShadow;
}
```

Comment: Is this for a shadowed table view?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apple's *[Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html)* has a subsection titled "The Compiler Handles CF Objects Returned From Cocoa Methods", which uses `CAGradientLayer.colors` as an example.  It says this code will work as-is:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = (CAGradientLayer *)[self layer];
        gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor],
                                                         (id)[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor], nil];
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0);
    }
    return self;
}
```

So maybe you should try rewriting your code like this:

```
- (CAGradientLayer *)shadowAsInverse:(BOOL)inverse
{
    CAGradientLayer *newShadow = [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];
    CGRect newShadowFrame =
        CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width,
            inverse ? SHADOW_INVERSE_HEIGHT : SHADOW_HEIGHT);
    newShadow.frame = newShadowFrame;
    UIColor darkColor =
        [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:
            inverse ? (SHADOW_INVERSE_HEIGHT / SHADOW_HEIGHT) * 0.25 : 0.25];
    UIColor lightColor =
        [self.backgroundColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0];
    newShadow.colors = inverse
        ? [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[lightColor CGColor], [darkColor CGColor], nil]
        : [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[darkColor CGColor], [lightColor CGColor], nil];
    return newShadow;
}
```

Comment: As a note, I've edited the above sample code from Apple, because the documentation is missing the cast to (id) for the CGColorRefs returned from the `-CGColor` methods.  This is a known documentation bug: https://devforums.apple.com/message/550670 and will lead to a compiler error if you use their code as they present it in the current documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem in another way:

In Xcode, in the target Build Phases tab, open the group to reveal Sources Compile the source file list. Double-click the file you want to for Which the flag in September, enter-fno-objc-arc in the pop-up panel, Then click Done.

This disables the ARC file only gives you problem.